# Utilizing container and element from Pickup block in function

Tags: anylogic

When utilizing the pickup block, I'd like to utilize the specific container and element passing through in a function. The container type is specified as my Forklift agent and the element type is specified as my Pallet agent. In calling my function f_pickupPallet, I have 3 arguments: (movementNbr, truck, and currentpallet). The error I get is "element cannot be resolved to a variable". Could someone direct me if I incorrectly added the arguments or names in the function?

f_pickupPallet:

```
Forklift fl = truck;
Pallet cp = currentpallet;

//Adjust inventory based on movement
fl.v_movementNbr = movementNbr;
if (movementNbr==1) {
    truck.add_pallet();
} else if (movementNbr==2) {
    truck.add_pallet();
    v_inventoryRawMat--;
} else if (movementNbr==3) {
    truck.add_pallet();
    v_inventoryRawMat--;
} else if (movementNbr==4) {
    truck.add_pallet();
    if (currentpallet.v_palletCurrentNode==storeMinIng) {
        v_inventoryMinIng--;
    } else if (currentpallet.v_palletCurrentNode==storePreBulk) {
        v_inventoryPreBulk--;
    }
} else if (movementNbr==5) {
    truck.add_pallet();
    if (currentpallet.v_palletCurrentNode==storeMinIng) {
        v_inventoryMinIng--;
    } else if (currentpallet.v_palletCurrentNode==storePreBulk) {
        v_inventoryPreBulk--;
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "on exit" code box only allows you to access the `container`, not the loaded `element`s:
[image]

You can access the element only in the "on pickup" code box via the `agent` keyword:
[image]

Learn more about the "magic lightbulb" helping you figure these things out here: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/magic-lightbulb